# Julia: Within data frame convert missing to 0

Tags: julia

In R we can convert NA to 0 with:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

This works for single columns:

```
df[ismissing.(df[:col]), :col] = 0
```

There a way for the full df?

Comment: On v0.7 this will be `coalesce.(df,0)`

Comment: This will not work on `df` I guess - you will still need `DataFrame(colwise(col->coalesce.(col, 0), df), names(df))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's such a function in `DataFrames.jl` yet.
But you can hack your way around it by combining `colwise` and `recode`. I'm also providing a reproducible example here, in case someone wants to iterate on this answer:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a = [missing, 5, 5],
           b = [1, missing, missing])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │ 1       │
│ 2   │ 5       │ missing │
│ 3   │ 5       │ missing │

julia> DataFrame(colwise(col -> recode(col, missing=>0), df), names(df))
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a │ b │
├─────┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0 │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 5 │ 0 │
│ 3   │ 5 │ 0 │
```

This is a bit ugly as you have to reassign the dataframe column names.

Comment: A bit shorter is `colwise(col->recode!(col, missing=>0), df)`. Also note that you could do `colwise(col->col[ismissing.(col)]=0,df)` but it is probably less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simpler way to convert all missing values in a DataFrame is to just use list comprehension:

`[df[ismissing.(df[i]), i] = 0 for i in names(df)]`

Comment: Minor nitpick, but given that you don't care about assigning the output of the comprehension, it would probably be better to just write this as a loop. If you want it to all be on one line, you can just do `for i in names(df) ; blah ; end`